# Powershell based replacement for WMI commands

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, system-information

I have an old script, its one of the first ones I wrote when i first started with Powershell. It uses `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem` and `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem`. Dusted it off for use on some users systems then found that some of the users have some sort of weird permissions issue for WMI and can't use the script. Personally, I never had an issue with it and never thought anyone else would.

So I'm looking to get away from the WMI/CIM instances and replace those with a .NET command or something else for use in the PowerShell script. Is there something else to use in the script besides the WMI/CIM instances? See script below I want to change

```
$Comp = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem); 
$DRole =   ($Comp).DomainRole;
switch ($DRole)
{
    0 {$DominRole = 'Standalone Workstation'}
    1 {$DominRole = 'Member Workstation'}
    2 {$DominRole = 'Standalone Server'}
    3 {$DominRole = 'Member Server'}
    4 {$DominRole = 'Backup Domain Controller'}
    5 {$DominRole = 'Primary Domain Controller'}
}
$PhyMem = [string][math]::Round(($Comp).TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB, 1);
$FreePhyMem = [string][math]::Round((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).FreePhysicalMemory/1024/1024, 1);
$cpux = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).Name;
$GBMem = $PhyMem + ' GB Physical Memory (' + $FreePhyMem + ' GB Free)';
Return $DominRole + ' - ' + $GBMem + '/' + $cpux
```

Comment: if you are not allowed the time to fix the CIM/WMI problem, you may be able to work around it by changing protocols. take a look at `Get-Help New-CimSessionOption -Parameter Protocol` - that seems to indicate that you can create a CIM session with a different protocol - and that may work around your glitch. ///// another way is to use the old msinfo32 util >>> `How to use System Information (MSINFO32) command-line tool switches — https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/300887/how-to-use-system-information-msinfo32-command-line-tool-switches` <<<

Comment: Thought about that, but gonna try something in systeminfo first, like > systeminfo | findstr /C:'Physical Memory' - but the problem with systeminfo its really slow but it turns out it works for those who could not do the WMI/CIM thing

Comment: you would think that here we are in the 21st century, and MS has not added a simple 'Get-Memory' command to powershell   :)

Comment: good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: i just remembered the `wmic` utility ... does that work on those systems? pro'ly not ... but it seems worth trying.

Comment: When you say "_weird permissions issue_", do you get an error message? Is it `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))` perhaps? In that case, have you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771551%28v%3dws.10%29) or [this](https://www.calazan.com/wmi-access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using at least PowerShell 5.1, [`Get-ComputerInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo) makes a lot of this information available.  You can see the relevant properties it provides with...

```
PS> Get-ComputerInfo -Property 'CsDomainRole', '*Memory*', '*Processor*'
```

Otherwise, you could use the classes in the [`System.Management` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management) to directly query WMI in much the same way `Get-WmiObject` would under the hood...

```
$selectedProperties = 'DomainRole', 'TotalPhysicalMemory'
# https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.selectquery
$query = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Management.SelectQuery' `
    -ArgumentList ('Win32_ComputerSystem', $null, $selectedProperties)
# https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher
$searcher = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher' `
    -ArgumentList $query

try
{
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.get
    $results = $searcher.Get()
    # ManagementObjectCollection exposes an enumerator but not an indexer
    $computerSystem = $results | Select-Object -First 1

    $domainRole = $computerSystem['DomainRole']
    $totalPhysicalMemory = $computerSystem['TotalPhysicalMemory']

    # Do something with $domainRole and $totalPhysicalMemory...
    $domainRoleText = switch ($domainRole) {
        0 { 'Standalone Workstation'   ; break }
        1 { 'Member Workstation'       ; break }
        2 { 'Standalone Server'        ; break }
        3 { 'Member Server'            ; break }
        4 { 'Backup Domain Controller' ; break }
        5 { 'Primary Domain Controller'; break }
        default { $domainRole.ToString() }
    }
    $totalPhysicalMemoryGB = [Math]::Round($totalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 1)
}
finally
{
    $computerSystem.Dispose()
    $results.Dispose()
    $searcher.Dispose()
}
```

It's hard to know if your issue is with WMI itself or the cmdlets accessing it without more detail, though.

Comment: yep, I tried that too. It works but takes wayyy too long and has to collect everything again for the whole system before you get what you need. But... I might end up doing that anyway. Not sure what exactly the issue is though, just know on those systems with the issue  it seems to be some sort of permissions thing with WMI, all the other cmdlets i've tried work fine, its just issues with that I posted in the original post.

Comment: @John I updated my answer with some PowerShell code to interact with WMI directly.  I also see that `Get-ComputerInfo` takes a `-Property` parameter, although it appears that just affects the properties present in the output; based on the progress bar it still queries all hardware and system properties whether you requested them or not, so that doesn't reduce execution time.

Comment: I used your code and put it in a little script, then emailed it to one of the users having issues. He just tried it and it works. Thank you very much. This is just getting weird - won't work with Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem and Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem on those system with the issue but works with your code.

Comment: @John That is strange, but I'm glad that works.  Out of curiosity, if you substitute `Get-WmiObject` for `Get-CimInstance` in your original code does it fail in the same way?

Comment: yes, it still fails on those machines having the issue. Not all of the machines had the issue but on those that do have the issue both Get-WmiObject and Get-CimInstance fail in the same way.

Comment: Have you checked those system for WMI/CIM corruption, that may be part of the issue, vs just permissions? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8/wmi-corrupt-how-to-reinstallrepair

Comment: yep, checked that yesterday. But got someone checking for something else today that looks like it may be the issue, someones been messing around with the systems on which the problem exists.